# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue-agile' in '../../.....'

Tags: vue.js

Установил vue-agile carousel https://github.com/lukaszflorczak/vue-agile ,

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueAgile from 'vue-agile'

Vue.use(VueAgile)


components:{
  VueAgile
}
```

использую docker,webpack выдает ошибку

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader

/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./server/vuejsapp/src/components/pages/landingPageVideo/index.vue
cm-frontend-alisa-anton_1  | Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue-agile' in '/app/server/vuejsapp/src/components/pages/landingPageVideo'
cm-frontend-alisa-anton_1  |  @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./server/vuejsapp/src/components/pages/landingPageVideo/index.vue 287:0-33
cm-frontend-alisa-anton_1  |  @ ./server/vuejsapp/src/components/pages/landingPageVideo/index.vue
cm-frontend-alisa-anton_1  |  @ ./server/vuejsapp/src/router/index.js
cm-frontend-alisa-anton_1  |  @ ./server/vuejsapp/src/app.js
cm-frontend-alisa-anton_1  |  @ ./server/vuejsapp/src/entry-client.js
cm-frontend-alisa-anton_1  | Child extract-text-webpack-plugin node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist node_modules/css-loader/index.js?{"minimize":true,"sourceMap":false}!node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler/index.js?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-36bfe88e","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":true}!node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"includePaths":["/app/server/vuejsapp/src/styles"],"sourceMap":false}!server/vuejsapp/src/styles/app.scss:
```

Что может быть ?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел причину, в json файле не компилилась строка с названием плагина))